# SPRESENSEのHDRカメラが暗闇だと起動しない

Tags: spresense, camera

SPRESENSEのHDRカメラ(CXD5602PWBCAM2W)を使用しようとしているのですが、暗闇だと写真が撮れないです。
公式サイトなどでは、「従来のセンサーでは対応が難しかった暗所や、 逆光などの明暗差の大きい環境でもクリアな映像が得られます」と書いているのですが、撮影自体をしてくれません。
cameraサンプルプログラムを書き換える必要があるのでしょうか。
開発環境はArduinoIDEでHDRカメラ発売前から使用しており、ArduinoIDE側の更新はしてHDRカメラは使えるようにしています。

Answer (score 1):

HDRカメラを利用していますが、ほとんど光のない暗闇ではさすがに画像は撮れません。
カメラで扱う最大照度は次のサイトを参考にすると100,000ルクスです。

https://canon.jp/business/trend/what-is-illuminance

HDRカメラのダイナミックレンジが120dBですので６桁が有効範囲になります。
ですので最低照度は0.1ルクスといったところでしょう。
ぎりぎり視界が効く薄暗い部屋の環境が限界といったところだと思います。
実際に使用してみても、それぐらいであればカラーで画像が撮れています。
まったく視認できない真っ暗な部屋だとさすがにノイズだらけの画像になってしまいます。